# Whatsapp sharing audio fails - "please try again"

Tags: android, whatsapp

I'm using this code for some years now and it worked fine:

```
final Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    sharingIntent.setType("audio/mpeg");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
        SoundProvider.getUriForSound(getContext(), sound));

    getActivity()
        .startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,
            getContext().getString(R.string.share)));
```

My `SoundProvider` generates a URI that starts with `content://` which is picked up by a `FileProvider` (actually the same `SoundProvider`). This provider reads an audio file from my `raw` folder.

The sounds was playable directly in WhatsApp (and not a generic file) and shown with the correct title from the ID3 tags.

This has worked flawlessly and still does with Telegram/Dropbox etc. but up until a recent WhatsApp update from a few months ago it fails with the message "Sharing failed please try again".

Is anyone aware of any changes made by WhatsApp and has encountered something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to work around this by copying the sounds to the [`external-files-dir`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)).

I don't know why whatsapp suddenly doesn't accept files from the `raw` directory served by a `FileProvider` anymore while other apps still do without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(audioPath);
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setType("audio/*");
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```

Comment: This does not work.
I already tried different MIME types (`mpeg`, `mpeg3`, `mp3`, `*`) but none of them work anymore with WhatsApp. Before all of them worked but not with all of them the audio was playable directly inside WhatsApp.